# Scrolling in panel freezes entire computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I have a panel that loads up a ton of pictures in a grid-like fashion. The issue is that when I scroll either vertically or horizontally it gets incredibly choppy/laggy and then after a few seconds of scrolling it locks the entire computer up for about a full minute.

This never happened on Windows 7 before according to my co-worker but for some reason on Windows 10 it does this and I am unsure why. I've looked around for a solution but nothing seems to resolve it. I tried disabling AutoScroll and add scroll bars to the form via code but they don't scroll the panel at all. Here is the code I tried it with if anyone can see where I messed up.

```
Dim hs As HScrollBar
    Dim vs As VScrollBar
    hs = New HScrollBar
    vs = New VScrollBar

    hs.Location = New Point(0, 438)
    hs.Size = New Size(1180, 15)
    hs.Value = 100
    hs.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
    vs.Location = New Point(1163, 0)
    vs.Size = New Size(15, 457)
    vs.Value = 0
    vs.Dock = DockStyle.Right

    Me.Controls.Add(hs)
    Me.Controls.Add(vs)

    vs.Enabled = True
    hs.Enabled = True
    pnlMap.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = True
    pnlMap.VerticalScroll.Enabled = True
```

Here is a picture of the Panel with the images loaded to try give some perspective to what the panel looks like.

[Form with panel full of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwuXC.png)

Can't tell if it's a VS issue or Windows at this point but as stated earlier it never did this on Windows 7. Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:
@idle_mind We tested this on multiple machines with Windows 10 and all of them locked up the PC for a minute or so. The images are at the top keft of the picture I shared above and then called into the panel if there is corresponding car type in the database. They're all sized 60x30, same as the images I just mentioned. Adding some more code below.

@Jimi I added the scrollbar code to see if anyone could help me at least figure our why the ones I added won't scroll the panel at all when I run it. Here is what we use to load the images into the panel if there's active car types in the database.

```
Private Sub Load_Railcars()
    Dim cm As MySqlCommand
    Dim rd As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sql As New StringBuilder
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim strType As String
    Dim intDays As Integer
    Dim datArrival As Date

    Try
        For i = 1 To Globals.TRACK_COUNT
            For j = 1 To Globals.TRACK_SPOT(i)
                picTrack(i, j).Image = BlankCar.Image
                picTrack(i, j).BackColor = Color.White
                ToolTip1.SetToolTip(picTrack(i, j), "Track: " & i & vbCr & "Spot: " & j)
                lblRR(i, j).Visible = False
            Next
        Next

        Select Case tabLegend.SelectedIndex
            Case 0
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAge.Rows
                    row.Cells("count").Value = 0
                Next
            Case 1
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvProd.Rows
                    row.Cells("count").Value = 0
                Next
            Case 2
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvCust.Rows
                    row.Cells("count").Value = 0
                Next
            Case Else

        End Select

        txtHopperCount.Text = "0"
        txtTankCount.Text = "0"
        txtOtherCount.Text = "0"

        sql.Append("SELECT rail.id, rail.name, rail.product_name AS prod_name, cust.name AS cust_name, rail.track, rail.spot, rail.type, rail.owner, rail.LE, rail.arrival_time, rail.release_time,")
        sql.Append(" prod.color_red AS prod_color_red, prod.color_grn AS prod_color_grn, prod.color_blu AS prod_color_blu,")
        sql.Append(" cust.color_red AS cust_color_red, cust.color_grn AS cust_color_grn, cust.color_blu AS cust_color_blu")
        sql.Append(" FROM storage AS rail")
        sql.Append(" LEFT JOIN product AS prod on rail.product_name = prod.name")
        sql.Append(" LEFT JOIN customer AS cust on rail.customer_id = cust.id")
        sql.Append(" WHERE rail.active=true")
        sql.Append(" ORDER BY track;")

        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(MYSQLCS)
            cm = New MySqlCommand(sql.ToString, cn)
            cn.Open()
            rd = cm.ExecuteReader
            If rd.HasRows Then
                While rd.Read()
                    y = rd.GetInt32("track")
                    x = rd.GetInt32("spot")
                    If y > 0 And x > 0 Then
                        ' Load the railcar image
                        If IsDBNull(rd.GetOrdinal("type")) Then
                            strType = ""
                        Else
                            strType = rd.GetString("type")
                        End If

                        Call Set_Railcar_Type(strType, rd.GetString("LE"), y, x)

                        ' Load the railcar backcolor based on the legend selection
                        Select Case tabLegend.SelectedIndex
                            Case 0  ' Age
                                If rd.IsDBNull(rd.GetOrdinal("arrival_time")) Then
                                    intDays = 0
                                ElseIf Date.TryParse(rd.GetDateTime("arrival_time"), datArrival) Then
                                    intDays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(datArrival).Days
                                Else
                                    intDays = 0
                                End If

                                If Not rd.IsDBNull(rd.GetOrdinal("release_time")) Then
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.Gray
                                ElseIf intDays > 30 Then
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.Red
                                    dgvAge.Rows(2).Cells("count").Value += 1
                                ElseIf intDays > 7 Then
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                                    dgvAge.Rows(1).Cells("count").Value += 1
                                Else
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                                    dgvAge.Rows(0).Cells("count").Value += 1
                                End If

                            Case 1  ' Product
                                If rd.IsDBNull(rd.GetOrdinal("prod_name")) Then
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.White
                                Else
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rd.GetInt32("prod_color_red"), rd.GetInt32("prod_color_grn"), rd.GetInt32("prod_color_blu"))
                                    dgvProd.Rows(Get_Legend_Row(dgvProd, "name", rd.GetString("prod_name"))).Cells("count").Value += 1
                                End If

                            Case 2
                                If rd.IsDBNull(rd.GetOrdinal("cust_name")) Then
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.White
                                Else
                                    picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rd.GetInt32("cust_color_red"), rd.GetInt32("cust_color_grn"), rd.GetInt32("cust_color_blu"))
                                    dgvCust.Rows(Get_Legend_Row(dgvCust, "name", rd.GetString("cust_name"))).Cells("count").Value += 1
                                End If

                            Case Else
                                picTrack(y, x).BackColor = Color.White
                        End Select

                        ' Load the railroad owned image if specified
                        If rd.GetString("owner") = "SYSTEM" Then
                            lblRR(y, x).Visible = True
                            lblRR(y, x).BringToFront()
                        Else
                            lblRR(y, x).Visible = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
            End If

            rd.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Call Globals.Error_Messager(Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name, "A SQL error occured loading the railcar. " & vbCr & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Name)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call Globals.Error_Messager(Me.Name, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name, "A general error occured loading the railcar. " & vbCr & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Name)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This could be anything, really.  Does it do lock up on ALL Windows 10 machines?  Do you have a Windows 10 machine with and without Visual Studio installed to test with.  Are you loading all those train car images from a file every time you need one?...or are they stored in your app for later use?  Are those images SMALL, or are they much larger and are scaled down in the picturebox? Etc...

Comment: Some code that adds scrollbars is not really helpful. Show the code section  that handles the Bitmaps.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I've added some answers to your inquiries to try and help. Thanks

Comment: @Jimi I added some more code to try and clarify the process

Comment: So, you have a ton of PictureBoxes, that - as it appears from the code you posted - are just used to set the background color of a *Cell* (a *Cell* of what?). Nowhere in this code I see you assign a Bitmap to these PictureBoxes, except the *blank image*. ++ You should not use PictureBoxes for this, no matter what a *Cell* is. How the `picTrack()` array is handled (how Control are added and, above all, removed from this collection) in unknown. How many times/how often is the `Load_Railcars()` method called?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of threading being used with `Load_Railcars()`, you're running a DB query and then iterating over a result and directly manipulating the user interface.  It's possible that Win10 has a different version of whatever back-end you're using and it treats things differently? (I'm not a DB guy, sorry).  But it does seem like it could possibly be a bottleneck point.  Have you tried running a profiler to see WHERE the slowdown is occurring?  Is it running the query? Updating the UI? Somewhere else?...

Comment: @idle_mind I don't think it's when the query is run since nothing happens when the panel is populated. It's only when I scroll the panel to see more of the car images. Do you have a recommendation for a profiler to use that may diagnose the issue?

Comment: I wonder if the controls that are not in view are not actually loaded until the panel is scrolled?  What is in `picTrack`?  Are they just normal PictureBoxes?...or are they a custom control or something else?

Comment: @Idle_Mind     Dim picTrack(Globals.TRACK_COUNT, 1000) As PictureBox

Public TRACK_COUNT As Integer

Comment: We're having the exact same problem with custom label controls instead of pictures.  The application still works fine on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2016, but Windows 10 hangs if we scroll up and down quickly.  Did anyone ever find anything to help with this?

Comment: Microsoft released an update last month for Windows 10 that appears to have fixed this issue for us.  No code changes, the problem just went away!